# Divide individual grouped items in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, division

Following `df`:

```
    appid   tag totalvalue
0   1234    B   50.00
1   1234    BA  10.00
2   2345    B   100.00
3   2345    BA  25.00
4   2345    BCS 15.00
```

What we want is to group the `df` with `appid` and have some analysis based on `tag` column, is such that if each `tag` is divided by `tag='B'` with `totalvalue`. Just like follows:

```
   appid    tag total    %tage(B)
0   1234    B   50.00    1    
1   1234    BA  10.00    0.2
2   2345    B   100.00   1
3   2345    BA  25.00    0.4
4   2345    BCS 15.00    0.15
```

Comment: In fact, I don't understand how do you group rows. Can you explain please especially the value of the last row?

Comment: @Corralien , I am grouping them using `appid`. In particular `appid` we can have multiple `tag`s available. But I want the ratios on the basis of `tag='B'` over others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
gmax = df['totalvalue'].where(df['tag'] == 'B').groupby(df['appid']).transform('max')
df['%tage(B)'] = 1 / (gmax / df['totalvalue'])
print(df)

# Output
   appid  tag  totalvalue  %tage(B)
0   1234    B        50.0      1.00
1   1234   BA        10.0      0.20
2   2345    B       100.0      1.00
3   2345   BA        25.0      0.25
4   2345  BCS        15.0      0.15
```

Comment: In this, you have consider the `max` value. But I want the value from `tag=='B'`

Comment: Can you check the values of `%tage(B)` column please?

Comment: I updated my answer with a new `gmax` calculation. Can you check it please?